# Move validator message inside function

Tags: laravel-5

I have a custom validator. I want to move the validator message inside the `my_validator` hook function.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'package_name' => 'required',
            'package_version' => 'required|my_validator'
        ],
        [
            'my_validator' => 'Some custom message.'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to add your validation message:

1. Using the `$message` array when using the `validate` function (as you've already done).
2. Adding your message to the `resources/lang/en/validation.php` lang file, as below:

```
return [
    // ...
    'my_validator' => 'Some custom message.',
    // ...
];
```